# Laravel 7.x - Using API Resources to Generate Pagination Links While Preserving Query String With Special Characters

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have an API written in Laravel that utilizes [Spatie Laravel Query Builder package](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-query-builder/v2/introduction/) to query a table and then return a JSON response using an [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources). Since this method acts sort of like a search feature as well, any pagination links should also include the additional parameters sent with the request. Here is an example:

**MessageController.php**

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $messages = QueryBuilder::for(Message::class)
            ->allowedFilters([
                AllowedFilter::exact('id'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('unread'),
            ])
            ->paginate(30);

        return MessageResource::collection($messages->appends($request->except('page')));
    }
}
```

This works great until you start to introduce special characters such a `[` or `]` into the url parameters. For example, we might send a request to `api/messages?filter[unread]=true` and we want the response to have a `links` section like the following:

**What We Want**

```
... Other JSON Data ...
"links": {
    "first": "https://test.test/api/messages?filter[unread]=true&page=1",
    "last": "https://test.test/api/messages?filter[unread]=true&page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
},
... Other JSON Data ...
```

**What We're Getting**

```
... Other JSON Data ...
"links": {
    "first": "https://test.test/api/messages?filter%5Bunread%5D=true&page=1",
    "last": "https://test.test/api/messages?filter%5Bunread%5D=true&page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
},    ... Other JSON Data ...
```

Is there an easy way to make it so that those special characters remain intact?

Comment: You might want to keep it like it is so that any program/person who uses your API doesn't have to URL encode those URLs again.

Comment: Yes, after further relfection, I think you're right, @DelenaMalan. I can then just url_decode the results. Thank you!